# Change an attribute value when a select query is run in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am implementing an inbox for my website where I mark all the read messages as 1 in the 'read' column.
Is it possible to automatically change the read value of a row to 1, whenever a select query is run on it.
I know I could do it by executing another query to change the value everytime I execute a select. But the code is in several different places. Can we simply do it on the SQL side??

Im using MySQL.
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more detail, what you have so far, etc..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: umm.. basically i have a table inbox with columns userid,sender,mesg and read. Evrytime a new entry is inserted, the default value for read(0) is set. What I want is that the read attribute should change to 1 everytime a select query is run on the table, which means the msg has been retrieved to be shiwn to the user

Comment: This could probably be done with a simple `update ... returning ..` in Postgres, but I have no idea how this could be done in MySQL.

Comment: I think having something update as soon as a select is run is dangerous. What is someone is just running a query on the table that has nothing to do with 'reading'?  using stored procedure for the select and update would be a better practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create `TRIGGER` unfortunately there is no `ON SELECT` trigger so you are out of luck there with automating this. I am afraid you will have to rely on server side.

Workaround would be to use stored procedure instead of direct `SELECT`, and each time execute `UPDATE` statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AUTOUPDATE(in InID INT)
   BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM [TABLE] 
     where [TABLE].ID = InID 
     UPDATE [TABLE] SET read = 1
     where [TABLE].ID = InID 
   END
```

you call stored procedures like this

`call AUTOUPDATE(1324);`

Comment: yes that is exactly the problem. There is no select trigger. And im using MySQL

Comment: Thanks!! I will try it out. BTW, is a procedure run atomically?

Comment: @user3838440 this only creates procedure, you would call it like this:  `call AUTOUPDATE(1324)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct - you want to update column each time some SQL is executed.

In that case I would try to [inject](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) UPDATE query inside SELECT query.

Comment: yes that is what Im trying to do...could you give an example